# Altering the DBSCAN Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, dbscan

I'm attempting to customize the DBSCAN algorithm so that it will **also** start a new cluster if the distance between two points in only the **x-direction** is greater than some number, or if the distance between two points in only the **y-direction** is greater than some number. However, I'm having some trouble doing this.

Here is my code so far:

```
     public void ComputeClusterDbscan(DatasetItem[] allPoints, double epsilon, int minPts, double[] currentpt, double[] nextpt, out HashSet<DatasetItem[]> clusters)
     {
        var allPointsDbscan = allPoints.Select(x => new DbscanPoint(x)).ToArray();

        int clusterId = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < allPointsDbscan.Length - 1 ; i++)
        {
            int j = i + 1;
            DbscanPoint p = allPointsDbscan[i];
            if (p.IsVisited)
                continue;
            p.IsVisited = true;
            DbscanPoint[] neighborPts = null;
            RegionQuery(allPointsDbscan, p.ClusterPoint, epsilon, out neighborPts);

            //calculate distance between points in x and y directions
            double xDirection = Math.Abs(allPointsDbscan[j].ClusterPoint.X - allPointsDbscan[i].ClusterPoint.X);
            double yDirection = Math.Abs(allPointsDbscan[j].ClusterPoint.Y - allPointsDbscan[i].ClusterPoint.Y);
            if (xDirection > 0.299 | yDirection > 0.199)
            {
                //begin new cluster
            }

            if (neighborPts.Length < minPts)
                p.ClusterId = (int)ClusterIds.Noise;
            else
            {
                clusterId++;
                ExpandCluster(allPointsDbscan, p, neighborPts, clusterId, epsilon, minPts);
            }
        }
        clusters = new HashSet<DatasetItem[]>(
            allPointsDbscan
                .Where(x => x.ClusterId > 0)
                .GroupBy(x => x.ClusterId)
                .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.ClusterPoint).ToArray())
            );
    }
```

Comment: This question is old so you have hopefully solved the problem. But you need to add the dx and dy comparison in the RegionQuery function and not the ComputeClusterDbScan function. RegionQuery determines if any given point could belong to the passed in point's cluster. It does this by adding each point to the neighbor list when it meets all the criteria for being considered a neighbor. In your case, in addition for needing to be within the specified epsilon distance, you'll further check that each point is within the projective x/y distances. If not, don't add to neighbor list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify DBSCAN to do this.

Three solutions:

1. Scale your data set such that the x and y thresholds are comparable to each other, then use maximum norm. I.e. if you have eps_x and eps_y, multiply your x coordinates with 1/eps_x, your y coordinates with 1/eps_y, and then use eps=1 with maximum norm.
2. Use weighted maximum norm
3. Use Generalized DBSCAN. E.g. in the ELKI implementation it is easy to add a new neighbor predicate that has two epsilon parameters. Take Intersection(neighbors_x, neighbors_y) as neighborhood.

Effectively all of these approaches change the "regionQuery" result.

Comment: Neither of these solutions solve my problem. Scaling will definitely not work, because I'm checking distances; and scaling the data down will only give me "false" positives.

Comment: You have to scale the data *exactly* as to match your desired thresholds. I'm not talking about normalizing them to [0;1]. Trust me, all three of them will work when done right.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean; please show me.

Comment: To put weight w on the x axis, multiply x with w. To put weight u on the y axis, multiply y with u!

Comment: lol I perfectly understand how to use scalar multipliers, but that WILL NOT help me with my dataset. Please keep in mind, I want to know if the distance (in only the x direction, is greater than some number of my choosing...say 0.5) OR if the distance (in only the y direction is bigger than say 1.5). And if it is bigger, in either direction, then start a new cluster. In this case, scaling will not help...it will only blow my data out of proportion when I try to figure out the distances.

Comment: That is what a) the *maximum norm* is for, or b) GDBSCAN, if you would read all of my answer. And not try to "prove" me wrong when I'm trying to help you.

Comment: Also, keep in mind, when I say "distance", its strictly one-dimensional...aka x2 - x1 = distance between points in x-direction, y2 - y1 = distance between points in y-direction. As a side note; I'm also using OxyPlot to see my data. I have the DBScan algorithm help me "color code" the clusters when they are run through the algorithm. And its not clustering with too good of an accuracy, which is why I want to implement this extra layer of "checking", so to say...and determine whether or not a new cluster should be started.

Comment: Please understand, I would LOVE for you to be correct.

Comment: I don't know...maybe I'm misunderstanding something. In your solution you say, then use eps=1 with maximum norm. Why use eps=1? and what EXACTLY do you mean by max. norm?

Comment: I'm not using Java...ELKI is not the way to go.